# Bash: delete based on file date stamp

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder with a bunch of files.  I need to delete all the files created before July 1st.  How do I do that in a bash script?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the following should do what you want:

```
touch -t 201007010000 dummyfile
find /path/to/files -type f ! -newer dummyfile -delete
```

The first line creates a file which was last modified on the 1st July 2010. The second line finds all files in /path/to/file which has a date not newer than the dummyfile, and then deletes them.

If you want to double check it is working correctly, then drop the `-delete` argument and it should just list the files which would be deleted.

Comment: After dropping the `-` in front of 'f', it now seems to list all the files.  If I drop the '!' it only lists the newer files.

Comment: I shamelessly stole/altered the answer from http://forums.devshed.com/unix-help-35/finding-a-file-modified-created-before-a-specific-date-468700.html

Comment: oh yes sorry, there shouldn't be a -f, just f.

Comment: I just double checked (and ran a quick test) and the correct command is indeed: find /path/to/files -type f ! -newer dummyfile -delete

Comment: never mind my previous comment.  It is only showing the older ones.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to delete files modified *after* a given date? It lists them fine without the "!" in `find /path/to/files -type f -newer dummyfile` but `-delete` doesn't work. Passing the output into a `for` loop with `rm` did the trick but there's an easier way, right?

Comment: If your `find` lacks the `-delete` option, try `-exec rm {} +` or if your `find` also doesn't support `-exec` with `+`, try `\;` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
find /file/path ! -newermt "Jul 01"
```

To find the files you want to delete, so the command to delete them would be:

```
find /file/path ! -newermt "Jul 01" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: Eric, what version of find has "newerct". I can't find that listed on any man page.

Comment: @bramp: GNU `find` has that option. However, Unix/Linux has no notion of a creation date, so I would use `-newermt`. The `c` is for the status change of the inode rather than "creation".