# how to know if a file was created after a certain time (bash)

Tags: file, time

I have a loop over files. So the file can be accessed with $f. I'd like to know if the file was created after a certain date and time

for example let's pick a time : 2015-05-22 and 14:11:00
I'd like to know if the file was created after that time

I know this is a way to find them
[How to use 'find' to search for files created on a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date)
but I want to check a file I'm looking instead. 
 I'm already in a loop over all files. Also I need to check day and time.

Comment: I'm assuming by `$f` you are using PHP. If you have the file name, have you looked into using the `filetime()` function? Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a different way following this post :

[Bash: delete based on file date stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676810/bash-delete-based-on-file-date-stamp)

I create the dummyfile at current date, then I execute my code, and after I compare the date with the dummy file as in the link explains